# The total size of the index is too large or too many parts in index in informix

Tags: database, indexing, informix, ddl

I am trying to run following script on informix:

```
CREATE TABLE REG_PATH (
    REG_PATH_ID SERIAL UNIQUE,
    REG_PATH_VALUE LVARCHAR(750) NOT NULL,
    REG_PATH_PARENT_ID INTEGER,
    REG_TENANT_ID INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY(REG_PATH_ID, REG_TENANT_ID) CONSTRAINT PK_REG_PATH
);

CREATE INDEX IDX1 ON REG_PATH(REG_PATH_VALUE, REG_TENANT_ID);
```

But it gives the following error:

> 517: The total size of the index is too large or too many parts in index.

I am using informix version 11.50FC9TL. My dbspace chunk size is 5M.

What is the reason for this error, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe 11.50 has support for large page sizes, and to create an index on a column that is LVARCHAR(750) (plus a 4-byte INTEGER), you will need to use a bigger page size for the dbspace that holds the index.  Offhand, I think the page size will need to be at least 4 KiB, rather than the default 2 KiB you almost certainly are using.  The rule of thumb I remember is 'at least 5 index keys per page', and at 754 bytes plus some overhead, 5 keys squeaks in at just under 4 KiB.

This is different from the value quoted by [Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31309552/15168).

See the [IDS 12.10 Information Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.welcome.doc/welcome.htm) for documentation about Informix 12.10.

- [Creating a dbspace with a non-default page size](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_0564.htm)
- [CREATE INDEX statement](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0401.htm)
- [Index key specification](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0406.htm)

This last reference has a table of dbspace page sizes and maximum key sizes permitted:

```
Page Size       Maximum Index Key Size
 2 kilobytes      387 bytes
 4 kilobytes      796 bytes
 8 kilobytes    1,615 bytes
12 kilobytes    2,435 bytes
16 kilobytes    3,245 bytes
```

If 11.50 doesn't have support for large page sizes, you will have to migrate to a newer version (12.10 recommended, 11.70 a possibility) if you must create such an index.

One other possibility to consider is whether you really want such a large key string; could you reduce it to, say, 350 bytes?  That would then fit in your current system.

Answer (score 1):

From the [informix documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0409.htm):

> You can include up to 16 columns in a composite index. The total width of all indexed columns in a single composite index **cannot exceed 380 bytes**.

One of the columns you want to add to your index is `REG_PATH_VALUE LVARCHAR(750)`; `750` bytes is longer than the `380` maximum allowed.

You can't "fix" this per se; either make the column size smaller, or don't include it in the index.

Comment: Is this a issue of version I am using or, is this happen in all informix editions and versions? Is other versions are using different limits?

Comment: @ChamilaWijayarathna You can check the documentation yourself, but I expect it will be constant across versions.